# c++ library refrencing compiler error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

this is a easy question but i cant seem to find the issue

```
    #include <iostream>
namespace utils {
    class IntList {
      public:
        IntList();                         // constructor; initialize the list to be empty
        void AddToEnd(int k);              // add k to the end of the list
        void Print(ostream &output); // print the list to output

      private:
        static const int SIZE = 10;      // initial size of the array
        int *Items;                      // Items will point to the dynamically allocated array
        int numItems;                    // number of items currently in the list
        int arraySize;                   // the current size of the array
    };
}
```

here i have defined a class in my header file

but it throws a compiler error saying that it cannot find a reference to ostream

Comment: `ostream` is in the `std` namespace, so you need `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class from the stl are in the namespace std.

So, unless you are doing `using namespace std`, you have to prefix them with `std::`. In your case you should be writing `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `std::` in front of ostream.

You can either :

1. use the whole namespace before your class definition : `using namespace std;` ;
2. mark that you'll be using std::ostream : `using namespace std::ostream;` ;
3. or write `std::ostream` everywhere you need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add `using namespace std` before calling `ostream`